# How can I appease Chrome's display of inputs (an image and a text input)?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, cross-browser

On http://powerbible.info, there is a text input, and an image submit input. They are declared inline, without formatting, and until recently the text input always appeared, as intended, to the left of the image input.

It still displays as intended in Firefox and Safari (haven't tried Internet Exploder), but not in Chrome. On Chrome the image input appears on top of the text input, to the left, and obscures the first few characters of anything the user types.

I could probably duct tape it into the intended place on Chrome, but I wanted to ask. What can I do so that Chrome recognizes the text input and the image input as two inline elements, the text before the image (separated only by a hidden input and whitespace)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `position: absolute;` in the css stylesheet for `input[type=image]`.  That absolute positioning is causing the submit button to overlap the text input.  Remove the absolute positioning and the overlap will stop.